# Как работают переменные в AWK

Tags: linux, bash, debian, awk

Есть директория с картинками:

```
1-TestOfMask.jpg
2-TestOfMask.jpg
3-TestOfMask.jpg
...
N-TestOfMask.jpg
...
asasdg.jpg
32rwef.jpg
```

Нужно посчитать количество картинок с маской и без маски через `awk`.
В данном случае считает нормально:

```
ls -f ./photo_dir | awk '
BEGIN {count_photo=0; count_mask=0;}
match($0, /(jpe?g|png|bmp)$/i) {count_photo++; count_mask++;}
match($0, /^[0-9]+\-TestOfMask\.jpe?g$/) {count_mask--;}
END {print count_photo,count_mask}'
```

Но статическая маска мне не интересна, у меня идёт перебор сотен масок:

```
name='TestOfMask'
ls -f ./photo_dir | awk '
BEGIN {count_photo=0; count_mask=0;}
match($0, /(jpe?g|png|bmp)$/i) {count_photo++; count_mask++;}
match($0, /^[0-9]+\-varmask\.jpe?g$/) {count_mask--;}
END {print count_photo,count_mask}' varmask=$name
```

В таком случае уже не находятся картинки с маской.

Также не понимаю почему не работает выражение `[0-9]{5,7}`:

`match($0, /^[0-9]{5,7}\-TestOfMask\.jpe?g$/)`

Пробовал писать так: `[0-9]\{5,7\}` и так `\[0-9\]\{5,7\}` всё бестолку.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, извините, очепятка, там закрывающая `'` и после `varmask=$name`, т.е. последняя строка такая: `END {print count_photo,count_mask}' varmask=$name`. Но от этого ничего не меняется, очепятка была только тут на форуме.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin что? 
`#!/usr/bin/env bash
t1='prnt'
ls -f ./ | awk '{print var}' var=$t1`

`$ ./testrn.sh
prnt
prnt
prnt
prnt
prnt
prnt
`

Comment: да, вы правы. *gnu/awk* (других реализаций сейчас под рукой нет) «проглатывает» такую ошибку.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а почему вы считаете это ошибкой? Это обычное задание переменной. В `man` такого нет - из книжки вычитал, да и в интернетах видал вроде.

Comment: поразмышляйте над результатом такого примера: `$ echo -e 'a\nb' | awk '{print x} x++'` и `$ echo -e 'a\nb' | awk 'x++ {print x}'`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это из разряда `$ echo -e 'a\nb' | awk '{print x} x++'` и $ `echo -e 'a\nb' | awk '{print x} ++x'`. По вашим примерам в первом случае идёт `print` пустого `x`, после инкрементирование и становление его `1`. Но инкрементирование это условие в синтаксисе `awk` и оно всегда `true`, значит после подставляется `{print}`, который печатает входящую строку. Второй случай по аналогии. За пример спасибо, но в отношении вопроса - это флуд.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21479520/10283136

Эту строку: `match($0, /^[0-9]+\-varmask\.jpe?g$/) {count_mask--;}`

Заменил на:

```
{varmask1="^[0-9]+\-"varmask"\.jpe?g$"}
$0 ~ varmask1 {count_mask--;}
```

**UPD:**

Строки выше можно заменить на:

`$0 ~ /^[0-9]+\-'$name'\.jpe?g$/`

Вопрос с `[0-9]{5,7}` актуален.

Comment: измените вопрос, пожалуйста. Добавьте ответ в upd к вопросу.

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto а что такого? Вопрос-ответ одним автором тут практикуется, вдруг кому полезно будет. А так увидят 0 ответов и пропустят, подумав, что нет ответа на вопрос.